# jQuery syntax Highlighting with SyntaxHighlighter?

Tags: jquery, syntax-highlighting

Is there any library available to use with SyntaxHighlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to highlight the jQuery Code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is JavaScript, so

```
<pre class="brush:javascript">...</pre>
```

should work with the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) from Alex Gorbatchev.

Comment: I meant which could highlight the jQuery functions.